# Access session[] in a FoosController.method in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session-variables

I have a

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    session[:comments] ||= {}
    comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    # Validation and such
    session[:comments][comment.post_id] = comment
    #several redirections and remote authentications. User returns to another method, 
    # But for the sake of the example, we continue here. 
    CommentsController.publish_from_session
  end

  def self.publish_from_session
    session[:comments].each do |comment|
      comment.save!
    end
  end
end
```

This gives me a *can't convert Symbol into Integer* error. When diving into this, apparently `session` is simply not available, or not a hash. It might be that calling `CommentsController.some_method` is plain wrong.

What would be the correct solution?

Also: As mentioned in the commented code, the real deal is a bit more complex. The user returns either on another controller (sessions controller via oauth) or on yet another method on the CommentsController. See [controllers calling eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233764/refactoring-and-decoupling-rails-controllers-can-they-call-eachother) and [Comments created after Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045689/saving-the-comment-object-after-successfull-oauth-login-with-rails-omniauth) for how I came to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session` is an instance method. You can't access it in a class method, but you can *pass* it (or just `session[:comments]` to the class method.

Comment: I, indeed, managed to pass it. I was just hoping that it would be available somehow, by changing the way I call the method; that would keep the code a lot cleaner.

Comment: Well, you could either change `publish_from_session` to an instance method or create an instance method wrapper for it, depending upon your needs.